# Hotelbed API request Codeigniter

Tags: php, api, codeigniter

I am totally new to this *hotelbed API*, is there anybody done before please guide me how to get result from this API using Codeigniter frame work?

I have tried their code, but I couldn't:

```
<?php
$apiKey = " ";
$Secret = " ";

$signature = hash("sha256", $apiKey.$Secret.time());

$endpoint = "https://api.test.hotelbeds.com/hotel-api/1.0/status";

//echo "Your API Key is: " . $apiKey . "";
//echo "Your X-Signature is: " . $signature . "";

try
{
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_URL => $endpoint,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => ['Accept:application/json' , 'Api-key:'.$apiKey.'', 'X-Signature:'.$signature.'']
    ));
    $resp = curl_exec($curl);

    if (!curl_errno($curl)) {
        switch ($http_code = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE)) {
            case 200:  # OK
            echo "Server JSON Response:" . $resp;
            break;
        default:
            echo 'Unexpected HTTP code: ', $http_code, "\n";
            echo $resp;
        }
    }
    curl_close($curl);

} catch (Exception $ex) {
     printf("Error while sending request, reason: %s\n",$ex->getMessage());
```

}
?>

Comment: What's the error ? (if there's any)

Comment: empty response i guess request was totally wrong

Comment: And do you have `curl` installed?

Comment: yes curl installed

Answer (score 0):

I ran this code and it was fine for me:

```
Server JSON Response:{"auditData":{"timestamp":"2017-11-09 10:25:04.503"},"status":"OK"}
```

It must be a problem with your setup. Have you uncommented php_curl & php_openssl in your php.ini? What server are you using?

Is the "Server JSON Response:" even printing at all?

Maybe try running an availability request and see if you are getting the same problem (https://github.com/hotelbeds-sdk/hotel-api-sdk-php/issues/107#issuecomment-342760756)